# React Router- Route different page based on browser type

Tags: redirect, react-router

I'm building a website for a client and I need to be able to route to a page only if the user is on a mobile browser. If the user is not on a mobile browser, instead a modal popup is displayed. Currently I can detect the browser type and open the modal if the user is on desktop, but I am failing to route the page if the user is on mobile.

this is my current code for the function, which is being passed from index.js to the component with a button which has the the swapContactModal function assigned as an onClick.

If the user clicks this button on desktop, it successfully swaps the local state value for the modal, displaying it. However, hist.push is pushing the address "/testimonials" to the address bar but does not cause the page to swap to the new view.

How can I get it to successfully swap to the /testimonials page inside this function?

Thanks in advance!!!

````
    if (isMobile === null) {
      setMobileOpen(false);
      setContactModal(!contactModal);
    } else if (isMobile !== null) {
      setMobileOpen(false);
      hist.push('/testimonials')
    }
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by using both history.push and history.go like so

```
if (isMobile === null) {
      setMobileOpen(false);
      setContactModal(!contactModal);
    } else if (isMobile !== null) {
      setMobileOpen(false);
      hist.push('/testimonials')
      hist.go()
    }
  };
```